# django admin page not showing same results as tutorial 2 from documentation. Why?

Tags: django

My code follows django's tutorial 2 on the admin page.  I'm just so confused why I don't get two entries to put inside the admin Change Blog page.  Anyone has an idea.

```
from blogs.models import Blog,Entry
from django.contrib import admin

class EntryInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Entry
    extra = 3

class BlogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [(None,{'fields': ['name']})]

    inlines = [EntryInline]

list_display=('tag_line')
```

admin.site.register(Blog, BlogAdmin)

Comment: Looks okay to me. Maybe the page is cached? Or try restarting the server.

Answer (score 0):

Are these lines in an `admin.py` and your `URLconf` is setup correctly for [autodiscovery](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#hooking-adminsite-instances-into-your-urlconf) of the ModelAdmins?

Does ommitting the fieldsets make a difference?

Make sure your model has a [unicode-method](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#unicode), or try use [list_display](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) to represent you model in the changelist by list of selected fields.
In your example `list_display` is not indented correctly:
Check the example for [PersonAdmin](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) in the docs:

```
class BlogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('post_title', 'post_author')
```

Comment: Thanks for all your pointers.  These lines are in admin.py of app directory.  URLconf of project has the  "from django import admin \n admin.autodiscovery".  Ommitting fieldsets didn't make a difference.  all models have unicode-method.

Comment: In code it is autodiscovery().  I really don't understand why the Entry objects aren't being displayed underneath Blog object in admin.  I restarted the server.

Comment: I wonder if copying base.html base_site.html and index.html from /django/contrib/admin/templattes/admin/ to my admin of project template directory has anything to do with this.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Also, the Entry object has a many-to-many field.  Don't know if that does affect anything here.

Comment: Thanks all.  Figured it out after restarting the server.

Comment: My problem was that the app was being served using fastcgi in production.  That caused me to not easily find my error that there was no field named tag_line.  It was supposed to be tagline. Very simple error.  sorry for the trouble.